# using protractor with Aurelia gives error

Tags: protractor, aurelia, enoent

I am trying to do e2e testing with protractor for aurelia project. 
`this is my protactor.conf.js`

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  //seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4444',
  // add proper version number
  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar',
  specs: ['test/e2e/dist/**/*.ts'],

  plugins: [{
    path: 'aurelia.protractor.js'
  }],


  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

this is demo.spec.ts

```
import {PageObject_Welcome} from './welcome.po';
import {PageObject_Skeleton} from './skeleton.po';

describe('aurelia skeleton app', function() {
  let po_welcome: PageObject_Welcome;
  let po_skeleton: PageObject_Skeleton;

  beforeEach( () => {
    po_skeleton = new PageObject_Skeleton();
    po_welcome = new PageObject_Welcome();

    browser.loadAndWaitForAureliaPage("http://localhost:9000");
  });

  it('should load the page and display the initial page title', () => {
    expect(po_skeleton.getCurrentPageTitle()).toBe('Welcome | Aurelia');
  });

  it('should display greeting', () => {
    expect(po_welcome.getGreeting()).toBe('Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!');
  });

  it('should automatically write down the fullname', () => {
    po_welcome.setFirstname('Rob');
    po_welcome.setLastname('Eisenberg');

    // For now there is a timing issue with the binding.
    // Until resolved we will use a short sleep to overcome the issue.
    browser.sleep(200);
    expect(po_welcome.getFullname()).toBe('ROB EISENBERG');
  });

  it('should show alert message when clicking submit button', () => {
    expect(po_welcome.openAlertDialog()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should navigate to users page', () => {
    po_skeleton.navigateTo('#/users');
    expect(po_skeleton.getCurrentPageTitle()).toBe('Github Users | Aurelia');
  });
});
```

when i run gulp watch , it run the project in the browser ,when i fyn gulp e2e ,
it gives the below error

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

```
Error: spawn C:\Automated_Testing\Vetserve.Web\src\Vetserve.Web.Appts\node_modu
es\.bin\protractor.cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

can someone help me with this

Comment: The error you're getting is saying that the file, `C:\Automated_Testing\Vetserve.Web\src\Vetserve.Web.Appts\node_modu
es\.bin\protractor.cmd`, doesn't exist. Does it exist?

Comment: yes it exists there

Comment: @thebluefox I have removed some at marks since it doesn't allow me to publish the comment
IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\protractor\bin\protractor" %*
) ELSE (
  SETLOCAL
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\protractor\bin\protractor" %*
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for this ,It was not relevant with aurelia,node or npm .I have mistakenly updated the environment variable "comSpec" instead of PATH
This variable "comSpec" can only hold one path ,this was the real issue for all the protractor errors